# wordpress use single ajax in place of multiple ajax requests in a smarter way

Tags: functions, ajax, templates

In wordpress I have database tables like this

```
product name

id product_name

1   A
2   B
3   C
4   D

product_buying_price

id product_name  product_buying_price
1   A                               10
2   B                           12
3   C                               15
4   D                               18

product_selling_price

id product_name product_selling_price
1   A                               12
2   B                           13
3   C                               19
4   D                               23
```

So I have a dropdown like this

```
<select name="product_name" id="product_name">
    <option value="">Products</option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="D">D</option>
</select>
```

and I want to show the values for product buying price and product selling price inside a table like this

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select name="product_name" id="product_name">
                <option value="">Products</option>
                <option value="A">A</option>
                <option value="B">B</option>
                <option value="C">C</option>
                <option value="D">D</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td class="product_buying_price"></td>
        <td class="product_selling_price"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Like this I have more around 3-4 such fields and I want to get those values for the product.

In the js file I have made the ajax like this

```
$('body').on('change','#product_name', function() {
    var selected = $(this).val;

    //Get product buying price
    $.post( test.ajaxUrl, { 'selected' : selected,  'action' : 'get_product_buying_price' }, function(data){
        data = $.parseJSON(data);
        selected.find('td.product_buying_price').html(data);
    });

    //Get product selling price
    $.post( test.ajaxUrl, { 'selected' : selected,  'action' : 'get_product_selling_price' }, function(data){
        data = $.parseJSON(data);
        selected.find('td.product_selling_price').html(data);
    }); 
});
```

Inside function I have the function like this

```
function get_product_buying_price() {
    global $wpdb;
    $selected_product = $_POST['selected'];
    $get_product_price = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT `product_buying_price` FROM `product_buying_price` WHERE `product_name` = '.$selected_product.' ");
    $product_buying_price = $get_product_price->product_buying_price;
    echo json_encode($product_buying_price);
    exit;
}

function get_product_selling_price() {
    global $wpdb;
    $selected_product = $_POST['selected'];
    $get_product_price = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT `product_selling_price` FROM `product_selling_price` WHERE `product_name` = '.$selected_product.' ");
    $product_selling_price = $get_product_price->product_selling_price;
    echo json_encode($product_selling_price);
    exit;
}
```

Here its working fine. But don't you think that doing multiple ajax request on one click makes it slow? I have around 3-4 request for one change. So can someone tell me some smarter way to achive this? Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I appreciate your question is quite old and you no doubt already have your solution but hopefully this may help someone else.

You could replace your javascript `post` calls with a single call to a single function that extracted both parts of data and returned them as an object.

```
$('body').on('change','#product_name', function() {
    //Get product prices
    $.post( test.ajaxUrl, {
            'selected' : $(this).val(),
            'action' : 'get_product_prices'
         }, function(data){
             data = $.parseJSON(data);
             $(this).parent('tr').find('td.product_buying_price').text(data.buying)
             .end().find('td.product_selling_price').text(data.selling);
    });
});
```

Then your php function would look like this.

```
function get_product_prices(){
    global $wpdb;
    $returnData = array();
    $selected_product =  esc_sql($_POST['selected']);
    // please see the notes on your database structure
    $get_product_price = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT `product_buying_price` FROM `product_buying_price` WHERE `product_name` = '.$selected_product.' ");
    $returnData['buying'] = $get_product_price->product_buying_price;
    $get_product_price = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT `product_selling_price` FROM `product_selling_price` WHERE `product_name` = '.$selected_product.' ");
    $returnData['selling'] = $get_product_price->product_selling_price;
    echo json_encode($returnData);
    exit;
}
```

I'm not hugely familiar with the wpdb class; it may be possible to replace your sql queries with a single query like this

```
SELECT `product_buying_price`.`product_buying_price`,  `product_selling_price`.`product_selling_price`
FROM `product_buying_price`
INNER JOIN `product_selling_price`
ON `product_buying_price`.`product_name` = `product_selling_price`.`product_name`
WHERE `product_buying_price`.`product_name` = '.$selected_product.'"
```

However from the look of your database tables, you appear to have an unnecessary number of tables and would be better to just store all data in one table

```
product_data

id   product_name  product_selling_price  product_buying_price
1    A             12                     10
2    B             13                     12
3    C             19                     15
4    D             23                     18
```

I'd also apply some checks within the PHP and Javascript to ensure you have all the required data for input into your html table.